# Get_post not displaying data

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type testimonial and am trying to display the title, content and the featured image.

This is my code:

```
    <?php
$args = array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'testimonial');
$testimonialsposts = get_posts($args);
?>
<div class="row">
    <?php
    foreach ($testimonialsposts as $post)
    {

    setup_postdata($post);
    ?>

    <div class="testimonial-box projectitem">
        <img src="<?= get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_attached_file', true); ?>"/>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-contact">
        <div class="testimonial-text"><?= get_post($post->ID, 'content', true); ?></div>
        <div class="testimonial-name"><?= get_post($post->ID, 'post_title', true); ?></div>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata();
        } ?>
    </div>
```

But I am getting nothing. When I tried to echo the details after setup_postdata its only echoing "array".

When I var_dump the $post it shows all the data also.

This is what i get when I `var_dump` `$post`

> object(WP_Post)#614 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(69) ["post_author"]=>
>   string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2017-08-22 02:26:43"
>   ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2017-08-22 02:26:43"
>   ["post_content"]=> string(575) "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
>   the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
>   industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
>   printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
>   book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
>   electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
>   popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
>   containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
>   publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
>   Ipsum." ["post_title"]=> string(13) "testimonial_1" ["post_excerpt"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish"
>   ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6)
>   "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(11)
>   "testimonial" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2017-08-22 02:27:07"
>   ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2017-08-22 02:27:07"
>   ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["guid"]=> string(63)
>   "http://192.168.0.202/clinic202/?post_type=testimonial&p=69"
>   ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(11) "testimonial"
>   ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" }

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use `print_r()` instead of `echo()` to display the contents of an array. If that doesn't help, please update your post to say if the array was empty or what it contained

Comment: @FluffyKitten i have updated my qn

Comment: You didn't need to post the whole lot, just let us know it was working :-) OK, so your query is working, but you loop is all wrong - you are using `get_post` for some reason instead of just using `get_the_title` or `get_the_content`, and you are not closing your `testimonial-contact` div in the correct place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you are using `get_posts` but this is what i would do, query the posts and loop by using `wordpress` loop instead using `foreach`.

try this

```
<?php
    query_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'testimonial',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ));
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <div class="testimonial-box projectitem">
         <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), '', 'false', array( "class" => "img-responsive" ) ); ?>
     </div>
    <div class="testimonial-contact">
        <div class="testimonial-text"><?php the_content();?></div>
        <div class="testimonial-name"><?php the_title(); ?></div>

    </div>
<?php endwhile; endif;
      wp_reset_postdata();
      wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

also you are closing `foreach` inside `<div>` which will break your `html` code.

Comment: i am facing a problem though when i added one more xtra testimonial the site gets disrupted and the testimonials dosent get displayed.
this code works for a single testimonial to be displayed.. Why so

Comment: try setting `posts_per_page` to some value and check if it works.